# Communication between two childViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiviewcontroller

What is the best way to communicate between two child view controllers ? I know the use of delegates to communicate between child and parent view controller but i am not able to get how to communicate between child view controllers of same parent view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could solve it with outlets what is the worse solution to my mind. Or you could inform your `parentViewController` about everything that happens and let him do the work (e.g. inform all objects that need specific information).

You would do it like this for example:

```
[childViewControllerInstance.parentViewController methodToCall];
```

In the class of the parent view controller you could then do everything you want and perform actions on whatever object is needed.

**EDIT:**

Please try

```
[childViewControllerInstance.parentViewController performSelector:@selector(methodToCall:) 
                 withObject:yourObjectToPass];
```

Comment: In childviewcontroller i have added this method -           -(IBAction)textButtonAction:(id)sender {
    
    [self.parentViewController drawTextSction:sender];
}  But this is giving me error not visible interface uiviewcontroller defines textButtonAction.

Comment: So my hint worked for you and you are letting your `parentViewController` do the work for you after having informed him?

Comment: Yes i am working the same thing. But i am getting the above error after calling the method from child view controller